# Best way to replicate a Canvas in Glance Widget?

Tags: android, glance-appwidget, glance

In Compose we have the method [Canvas()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Canvas) to draw lines etc.

Is there a similar feature in Glance? If not, what would be the best way to replicate the Canvas functionality?

Comment: `RemoteViews` -- which is what Glance's compositions turn into -- does not support arbitrary widgets, nor directly passing images, drawing paths, the platform `Canvas` type, etc. You could try using regular Compose UI to render your desired image (via `Canvas()`) to a `Bitmap`, then use [`ImageProvider(Bitmap)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/glance/package-summary#ImageProvider(android.graphics.Bitmap)) and `Image()` to display it in a Glance composable.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, this is something that I have looked at before however it seems unusually hard to convert a [composable to a bitmap](https://proandroiddev.com/create-bitmaps-from-jetpack-composables-bdb2c95db51). Are you able to provide a simple example? This should suffice as a valid answer under the 'alternative' route.

Comment: "it seems unusually hard to convert a composable to a bitmap" -- there are libraries for that, such as [this one](https://github.com/PatilShreyas/Capturable), [this one](https://github.com/KaustubhPatange/kapture), and [this one](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Screenshot). "Are you able to provide a simple example?" -- nope. I peeked at the Glance API and saw that they had `ImageProvider(Bitmap)`, which unlocked this approach, but I haven't tried it. If you get it working, post an answer to your question!

Comment: @CommonsWare I am still looking into this approach. have asked another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74252634/15597975) as an offshoot if you care to take a look.

Comment: @CommonsWare for further information, I would like to use existing composables I have created in my app for the widgets too (remote views). when the user clicks on the widget, I am starting a worker, which needs to create the bitmap from the composable. These composables use `canvas()` and so cannot be created directly in glance. All approaches I have come across require starting an activity to do the "composable to bitmap" function.

Comment: @mars8 where you able to draw the canvas in glance widget?