# How to convert a ComposeView to Bitmap?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-bitmap

I have a simple activity which I am using to convert a `composeView` to `Bitmap`.

However when I run the below `myBitmap` is blank and does not show the "Hello" text composable.

How can I make the below convert `composeView` to Bitmap?

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val widthPx = 200
        val heightPx = 120

        val composeView = ComposeView(applicationContext)
        composeView.setContent {
            Text(
                text = "Hello",
                color = Color.Black,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize()
                    .background(Color.Green)
            )
        }

        val myBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthPx,heightPx,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

        val myCanvas = Canvas(myBitmap) 
        composeView.draw(myCanvas)
        val result = myBitmap /*<--- result is blank bitmap*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait until the view has been laid out

```
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                val bitmap = graphicUtils.createBitmapFromView(view = view, width = width, height = height)
                onBitmapCreated(bitmap)
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
            }
        })
```

taken from
https://proandroiddev.com/create-bitmaps-from-jetpack-composables-bdb2c95db51

Answer (score 0):

**You are missing this code**：`setContentView(composeView)`

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val widthPx = 200
        val heightPx = 120

        val composeView = ComposeView(applicationContext)
        composeView.setContent {
            Text(
                text = "Hello",
                color = Color.Black,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentSize()
                    .background(Color.Green)
            )
        }
        // Without this code, you need to render to the activity to take a screenshot
        setContentView(composeView)

        val myBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthPx,heightPx,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

        val myCanvas = Canvas(myBitmap) 
        composeView.draw(myCanvas)
        val result = myBitmap /*<--- result is blank bitmap*/
    }
}
```