# How to apply Android Code Search examples that use different source sets in Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, android-testing, glance-appwidget

I am looking at the source code for Glance Widgets on Android Code Search. I would like to replicate the code used for [CheckBoxTest.kt](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:glance/glance-appwidget/src/androidAndroidTest/kotlin/androidx/glance/appwidget/CheckBoxTest.kt) but running into an issue. The problem is the code uses a version of [GlanceAppWidget.kt](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:glance/glance-appwidget/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/glance/appwidget/GlanceAppWidget.kt;l=59?q=provideGlance&ss=androidx%2Fplatform%2Fframeworks%2Fsupport) which differs from GlanceAppWidget used in the [official api release](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/glance).

How can I replicate CheckBoxTest.kt in Android Studio so that it works with the Glance API provided in the official release.

For context, I am following the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334638/where-can-i-find-examples-of-testing-interactions-with-android-homescreen-widget) post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code merged in androidx libraries is deployed into SNAPSHOT versions of the library. See https://androidx.dev/

That being said, there is code in the CheckBoxTest.kt that is only for testing so you would need to copy those classes.

Comment: Is there any way to cleanly import the code into an Android Studio Project? I am getting infinite number of errors when I try manually copy and pasting in. Separate question raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75650557/how-to-import-repositories-from-cs-android-com)

Comment: I have raised another question on same topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75687020/15597975). Appreciate any help you may be able to offer.